# How to screen.debug and not display the information in the collapsed Accordion when running in jest?

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library

Is it possible to jest screen.debug and not show the information in an Accordion when it's collapsed ?

Thanks.

Comment: What information?

Comment: The information inside the Accordion.  If the Accordion is closed and I do a screen.debug(), it still display the information inside the closed Accordion.  Is it possible to screen.debug() or use other methods to display only what the user sees ?